# Load a JSON file at runtime

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

How do I load a local json file in react native project **at runtime** where the local file will be a variable name?

Example:

This works

```
var data = require("../../0001.json");
```

I want this to work:

```
var path = "../../0001.json";
var data = require(path);
```

I'm open to alternatives to *require*.

TLDR: How do I open a file at runtime in react native. Load local data files as required by the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using webpack, you could simply use [`require.ensure`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html). But since all you want to load is JSON data, why don't simply use [file API](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) to read the JSON into a stream and then use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the file IO API for this case? It sounds like what I want but I'm not seeing any examples when googling.

Comment: Here's a library which provides fs API in react-native env - https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs.